# Labeling a barchart with a tree of properties

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

Given a `DataFrame` with a number of properties. I would like to label the ticks of a bar chart in the sense of a tree. I hope the following example and ASCII-art makes it clear:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [
    ('foo', 'qux', 2, 2),
    ('bar', 'corge', 1, 3),
    ('foo', 'corge', 3, 2),
    ('bar', 'qux', 2, 3),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=('A', 'B', 'U', 'V'))

df.plot.barh(stacked=True)
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(df.A + ' ' + df.B)

# Should be
#
# foo / qux     |##@@
#     \ corge   |###@@
# bar / qux     |##@@@
#     \ corge   |#@@@
```

The actual data consists of three properties / levels of trees from a factorial experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proposed way using minor ticklabels to achieve the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker

data = [
    ('foo', 'qux', 2, 2),
    ('bar', 'corge', 1, 3),
    ('foo', 'corge', 3, 2),
    ('bar', 'qux', 2, 3),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=('A', 'B', 'U', 'V'))

df = df.set_index(['A','B'])
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
# Remove the index names for the plot, or it'll be used as the axis label
df.index.names = ['','']

ax = df.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)

minor_locator = ticker.AutoMinorLocator(2)

ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator)
ax.set_yticklabels(df.index.get_level_values(1))
ax.set_yticklabels(df.index.get_level_values(0).unique(), minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df), 2), minor=True)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', direction='out', pad=50)

plt.show()
```

[image: Bar chart with multiple levels of tick labels]

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea. Do you also have any idea how that could be extended to three levels?

Comment: You could also put all of them as the major tick labels, then iterate and use set_y to offset only some of them. Or create a secondary y-axis and use that.